# How do I reversibly remove_foreign_key on a table when the column doesn't match the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I tried the following

```
remove_foreign_key :users, :asset_types, column: :seek_asset_type_id
```

But got the error

> StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>   wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)

The documentation says it uses the same options as `#add_foreign_key`.

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key)

The column was created previously with

```
add_reference :users, :seek_asset_type, foreign_key: {to_table: :asset_types}
```

This is the definition:

```
"fk_rails_4dcaa1c59c" FOREIGN KEY (seek_asset_type_id) REFERENCES asset_types(id)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`revert`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-revert):

```
def change
  revert do
    add_reference :users, :seek_asset_type, foreign_key: { to_table: :asset_types }
  end
end
```

Another way is to revert a migration by its name:

```
def change
  revert AddAssetTypeReferenceToUsers 
  # I made up this migration name, 
  # so please fill in the appropriate name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a deficiency in `remove_foreign_key`, but you can work around it by defining an `add_foreign_key` inverse action using `reversible`:

```
reversible do |dir|
  dir.up do
    remove_foreign_key :users, column: :seek_asset_type
  end
  dir.down do
    add_foreign_key :users, :asset_types, column: :seek_asset_type
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove table_name

> remove_foreign_key :users, column: :seek_asset_type_id

Comment: But then it's not reversible. How would it know which table to re-create the foreign key with? It would think the table is named `seek_asset_types` when it's really called `asset_types`.

Comment: Okay, you can overwrite UP and Down method in the migrations to make it reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
I've tested it and work for me.

> remove_foreign_key :users, name: "seek_asset_type_id"